# Monthly/Weekly calendar with ViewPager and PageAdapter

Tags: android, calendar, flip, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I want to implement a monthly/weekly calendar with a ViewPager/PageAdapter to flip right and left (and see the content of the different views while flipping like android calendar under ICS!) within the months/weeks, but I have some problems with the PageAdapter implementation.

I have to implement the `getCount()` method from PageAdapter, but I have an unlimited number of views.

My other problem is to get the right view (or fragment?) in the `instantiateItem(View collection, int position)` method.
A further problem is that I want to flip left and right infinitely (not start at position 0 for the current month/week).

Comment: I have developed this code long back and kept my source available at **[my blog](http://pavandroid.blogspot.in/2010/09/how-to-create-calendar-in-android.html)** I think you need to customize as per your requirement. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hello Pavandroid, thx but you dont use a ViewPager in your activity.

Comment: I have the main functionality already. but i need help with doing it with a PageAdapter to get the flip right and left function. I cant flip left when i start at position 0, when i set startPosition to 100 i can only flip 99 to left...

Comment: did you figure out how to implement the viewpager?

Comment: yes i have a member variable m_count and in instantiate item i will look if the end is reached (position+1>m_count) for the next element. if true i will increment m_count to have the unlimited number of views.